# Sharepoint Feature Creation Approach

Tags: feature, feature-receiver

I want to create a feature,  once the feature is activated by the administrator a number of lists, items and workflows will be created.

What would be the best approach to implementing this?

The only way i have currently came across is using SPFeatureReceiver and creating the objects on the FeatureActivated function.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope following links will helps you,

http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/10/27/developing-sharepoint-2010-features-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

here how workflow realtes stuffs into featureactiviated.

http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2011/01/19/package-deploy-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

http://devendra-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/01/creating-list-programatically-in_30.html